# Using request.getParameter to obtain caption of a Button throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, nullpointerexception, submit-button

i have created jsp file with three `submit` buttons pointing to one `servlet`,when i try to get  the caption value as a `request parameter`
in the `servlet` it throws a `NullPointerException`,the `jsp` file is here:

```
<td>
  <input type="submit" id="user" name="user_submit" value="search" class="searchUserbutton">
  </td>
<div class="searchResultFrameButtonDiv">
        <input type="submit" name="user_submit" id="addrole" value=">>" onClick="send_roles();" class="addDelsearchUserbutton"><br>

        <input type="submit" name="user_submit" id="deleterole" value="<<" onClick="delete_roles();" class="addDelsearchUserbutton">

    </div>
```

This is the code that throws `NullPointerException` in my `servlet`:

```
 String caps=request.getParameter("user_submit");
 System.out.println("the caps value is"+caps);// prints null
```

Comment: If the second line prints anything, how can it throw a NPE?

Comment: Why are you giving the same name 'user_submit' to the input elements. When you submit form the form data is sent as name-value pairs and at server you retrieve the value using the name.

Comment: Use some HTTP debugging tools (such as firebug for firefox) and check your HTTP request, whether the parameter was send.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get from submit button,use `request.getParameter()` to retrieve from text fields like `<input type="text">`

Also there is no form so submit button will not work

Comment: there is onClick javascript call

Comment: And what does this javascript call actually do? You neglected to post it. Post ALL relevant code, not just a tiny snippet of it.

Comment: @Gimby Is the above comment meant for me?

Comment: ... no, I'm making a real mess of things; I misinterpreted Kojotak's reply as being a response from the OP. Jebus I have real trouble getting used to the Stackoverflow interface.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give same name to multiple `input` elements , because in `request.getParameter()` method it will select parameter by name , so it will make ambiguity .

Change your code like this :

```
 <td>
  <input type="submit" id="user" name="user_submit" value="search" class="searchUserbutton">
  </td>
<div class="searchResultFrameButtonDiv">
        <input type="submit" name="user_submit_add" id="addrole" value=">>" onClick="send_roles();" class="addDelsearchUserbutton"><br>

        <input type="submit" name="user_submit_delete" id="deleterole" value="<<" onClick="delete_roles();" class="addDelsearchUserbutton">

    </div>
```

And  in JSP page you can get parameter values by using corresponding parameter name.